# passing data from mvc controller to angular controller and scope

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

Within a MVC controller I am trying to pass a collection of data back to the view.

```
private string GetEntityList()
        {
            var entities = new[]
            {
               new EntityList{ EntityId = 1, EntityName = "Entity 1"},
               new EntityList{ EntityId = 2, EntityName = "Entity 2"},
               new EntityList{ EntityId = 3, EntityName = "Entity 3"},
               new EntityList{ EntityId = 4, EntityName = "Entity 4"},
               new EntityList{ EntityId = 5, EntityName = "Entity 5"}
            };

            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entities, Formatting.None, settings);
        }
```

And I send it to the view via a string model

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View("index","", GetEntityList());
}
```

Within my cshtml file I am trying to assign the model to a property called mvcData that a part of a service I define

app.factory("searchAttributes", function() {
            console.log(@Html.Raw(Model));
            return { mvcData:@Html.Raw(Model) };

        });

This script tag resides inside of my ng-app so its in the scope of the app however when I try to reference if from `app.controller` it appears as undefined

```
app.controller('searchController', ['$scope', 'searchService', 'ngNotifier', '$log', '$timeout', 'searchAttributes', function ($scope, searchService, searchAttributes, ngNotifier, $log, $timeout) {

    var vm = this;
    //bootstraped data from MVC
    $scope.searchAttributes = searchAttributes.mvcData;

}]);
```

Looking at the model when it is returned to the html I can see that it is a valid object. Using `console.log(@Html.Raw(Model)` I see objects coming back

```
 Object[0] entityId: 1   entityName: "Entity 1"
 Object[1] entityId: 2   entityName: "Entity 2"
```

Any ideas why this object isn't being picked up in the controller?  Even though I have it defined as a dependency it's as if the `ng-controller` doesn't detect it/load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are out of order:

```
app.controller('searchController', ['$scope', 'searchService', 'ngNotifier', '$log', '$timeout', 'searchAttributes', function ($scope, searchService, searchAttributes, ngNotifier, $log, $timeout) {
```

should be

```
app.controller('searchController', ['$scope', 'searchService', 'ngNotifier', '$log', '$timeout', 'searchAttributes', function ($scope, searchService, ngNotifier, $log, $timeout, searchAttributes) {
```

Your current code would mean your `searchAttributes.mvcData;` is actually referencing `timeout.mvcData` which is undefined.

Comment: That was it, man what an oversight on my part. Thanks for catching that

Comment: @rlcrews I've done that before and searched for hours before realizing it was so simple of a fix. I felt silly to say the least.